# Is it a good idea-Make view nil in viewdiddisappear?

Tags: memory-management, ios6, ipad-3

I am facing memory management problems in one of my iPad application which is in iOS6, wherein my application terminates due to large amount of dirty size. I have 5 view controllers which get created each time i tap them. So is it a good idea to unload the view in viewDidDisappear?

Comment: If the size is dirty, then clean it! :)

Comment: But how do I cleanup the dirty memory? Please explain,I have no idea about that.I am using too many images in the app,is it related to dirty size/resident size?

Comment: You do release your allocated memory right? Also, with no code or examples regarding what is dirty size or what memory are you allocating on creating viewcontrollers, how to help? Explain more!